# How to filter the results of Google AutoComplete API to show only full addresses

Tags: ios, google-maps, autocomplete, google-api, geocoding

By full address, I mean address that contains address number, street name, city, state, and country

Right now,
I call google autocomplete like:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?key=%@&type=geocode&input=%@&sensor=true
```

The problem is, the return does not guaranteed to be a full address(sometimes missing address number and street name)

Now I even tried changing the type parameter(types=address)

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?key=%@&types=address&input=%@&sensor=true
```

According to documentation "address instructs the Place Autocomplete service to return only geocoding results with a precise address", it should give back a precise address.
Nevertheless, the results can still be missing fields(I think mainly missing the address number)

Now is there any way I can filter out the result from autocomplete such that the return list is only places that contains address number, street name, city, state, and country?

One option that I can think of is to get the autocomplete result first and then reverse each one of the place_id(this will give me all the attributes[address number...city, state, country]), which will enable me to filter out the list locally on the client side. However this solution is too slow and makes too many request. If possible, I would not like go this option.

thanks,
Any comments, opinions, suggestions will be appreciated

Comment: If you put a coordinate from the pacific ocean to the API request, it wont return you a street name. Also, different country has different format of address, so an address in Japan wont match the format from an address in United States. The `type=address` will be the only possible restriction. Best way you can do is to use autocomplete first, then use the latlng or place id from the autocomplete API response to do a [reserve geocoding request](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding) to get the `address_components`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use AutocompleteService instead of Autocomplete.
You can then manually filter the list of results.

See example at this page:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-queryprediction

Hope it can help.